# storing array in session with zend frame work

Tags: zend-framework, session

I am stuck, I want to store and array in session

my code is something like below

```
$this->session->email['client'];
$this->session->email['admin'];
```

Actually I have 2 users, 1st is client and second is admin. So, want to store both's email.

This is not working for me can anyone suggest me.

Comment: Need more info what you want to do. What is $this, etc.

Answer (score 2):

How about putting an actual value:

```
$this->session->email['client'] = 'client@domain.com';
$this->session->email['admin']  = 'admin@domain.com';
```

or better yet like this

```
$users = array(
    'client' => 'client@domain.com',
    'admin'  => 'admin@domain.com'
);
$this->session->email = $users;
```